# How to change CSS in onChange typeScript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have 2 input fields, when the user inputs into one of them, I want to change the css of the other. For example, change class "changeAmount" to "display:none" when an onChange is triggered in "changeOffer".

```
<div>
   <Input class= "changeAmount"
        placeholder="Enter a number"
        value={values.amount}
        onChange={(_, value) => handleInput('amount', value)}
   />
</div>
<div>
   <Input class="changeOffer"
        placeholder="Enter a number"
        value={values.offer}
        onChange={(_, value) => handleInput('offer', value)}
   />
</div>
```

Also note that CSS is in separate file.
Edit:
This is what my handleInput looks like

```
const handleInput = (name, value) => {
    handleChange({ target: { name, value } });
  };
```

Comment: What do you have in `handleInput`?

Comment: Are you using plain CSS, or CSS in JS? If the former, you probably want to toggle a class that sets `display: none` rather than modify the class (static css files probably shouldn't be changed by your JS code). If the latter, we need to see more code to help you.

Comment: @ChrisGilardi I added the change to description.

Comment: @ConnorLow I just have a separate CSS file. There is no CSS in the typeScript file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to assume here you're using functional components. In that case, one potential solution to this problem you could try would be to hold the style information as state in the component. For example, you could do something like this:

```
export const MyComponent: React.FC = () => {
   const [isAmountDisplayed, setAmountDisplayed] = useState(true);
   const [isOfferDisplayed, setIsOfferDisplayed] = useState(false);

   const handleInput = (name: string, value: string) => {
      handleChange({ target: { name, value } });

      // Note this will just hide the other input as soon as you type 
      // in the first one, which is probably not what you want.
      // You'd need to add your logic here.
      switch(name) {
         case 'amount':
            setIsOfferDisplayed(d => !d);
            break;
         case 'offer':
            setAmountDisplayed(d => !d);
            break;
      }
   };

   return (
      <div>
         <Input class= "changeAmount"
              style={{
                  display: isAmountDisplayed ? 'inline' : 'none',
              }}
              placeholder="Enter a number"
              value={values.amount}
              onChange={(_, value) => handleInput('amount', value)}
         />
      </div>
      <div>
         <Input class="changeOffer"
              style={{
                  display: isOfferDisplayed ? 'inline' : 'none',
              }}
              placeholder="Enter a number"
              value={values.offer}
              onChange={(_, value) => handleInput('offer', value)}
         />
      </div>
   );
};
```

You could use a similar method, potentially using only one `useState`, depending on your use case. Note you could also use a similar method to apply a class to the elements instead of directly changing their styles, maybe something like this:

```
<Input className={`changeAmount ${isAmountDisplayed ? '' : 'hidden'}`} .../>
```

In conjunction with the [classnames](https://www.npmjs.com/package/classnames) package, you could clean it up a fair bit.